# trying to join two tables and get the count of how many comments were made about a department

Tags: sql, count, group-by

My sql is not working when trying to get the total number of comments that were made by each department.

```
select * from departments d
  COUNT( comments.department_id ) AS total_comments
FROM
  d
LEFT JOIN
  comments c
ON
  ( d.id = c.department_id )
GROUP BY
  d.id, d.title
```

comments.department_id = departments.id

UPDATE: I neglected to mention I want to display the results in this manner: departments.title (total_comments)

Example: Maintenance (4)

SOLVED: needed to group it by d.title as well, now GROUP BY is d.id, d.title

Comment: Do you need the `SELECT *` in there?  That's what's causing the issue...

Comment: Which database are you using MySQL or SQL Server 200(?)

Comment: @JNK I do not need *, but I need to get the count of comments.department_id.
@Gage - Oracle

Comment: I think Leslie's answer is your best chance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT departmentID, COUNT(*)
FROM COMMENTS
GROUP BY departmentID
```

if you need departments that have no comments:

```
SELECT d.DepartmentID, Count(c.DepartmentID)
FROM Departments d
LEFT JOIN Comments c on d.departmentid = c.departmentid
GROUP BY d.DepartmentID
```

Comment: In your second example, your table Comments needs to be labeled as c, no?